# How to change width of concrete \hline in table?

Tags: tables, rules

How can I change concrete `\hline` width? Maybe does anything exist like `\hline[2mm]`?

PS: `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2mm}` is inadequate in my situation because it changes all lines width in a table.

Comment: Use the `booktabs` package and its `\toprule[2mm]` or `\midrule[2mm]` or `\bottomrule[2mm]` commands instead of `\hline`, depending on the position of the `\hline`

Comment: You can use \noalign{\hrule height 2mm}

Answer (score 7):

A small 'showcase' of the `booktabs` rule width facilities.

In addition, the `booktabs` package allows the change of the separation of rules with respect to the cells. For this, I refer to the manual.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{p{12cm}}
\toprule[2mm]
\blindtext \tabularnewline
\midrule[5mm]
\blindtext \tabularnewline
\bottomrule[10mm]
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The rule widths are slightly exaggerated ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. I was surprised why standard LaTex without usage additional packages has no this simple feature? It's rhetorical question)

Answer (score 6):

without booktabs you can do

```
....\\
\noalign{
\global\dimen1\arrayrulewidth
\global\arrayrulewidth5pt
}\hline
\noalign{
\global\arrayrulewidth\dimen1 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use vertical rules (not recommended in general), `booktabs` is not compatible. But you can do that:

- either with the `boldline` package, from the `shipunov` bundle which defines a `\hlineB{num}`, a `\clineB{c1-c2}{num}` commands, and a `V{num}` intercolumn specifier for vertical rules. `Num` results in a `num × \arrayrulewidth`.
- or with the `makecell` package, which has a `\Xhline{length}`and a `\Xcline{c1-c2}{length}` commands.

Demo:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage[x11names, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
  \begin{tabular}{V{2.5}c|c|cV{1.6}}
    \hlineB{3}
    Fiddle & Dee & Dee \\
    \hlineB{2}
  \end{tabular}
  \vskip 3ex
  \begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width2pt}c|c|c!{\vrule width2pt}}
    \Xhline{3pt}
    Fiddle & Dee & Dee \\
    \Xhline{2pt}
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is is possible to get \Xhline set a blue ou red line? I' didn't find any parameter to change the default color black.

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know, it's not possible. I once tried to patch the code which defines these lines (and the more or less equivalent lines defined  in `makecell`), but it didn't work. A solution is to use the `\specialrule` command from `booktabs`, for which you can remove the padding around rules, and which obeys the`arrayrulecolor` command.