# how to specify line width and line color in longtable environment

Tags: color, longtable, width

In longtable environment (as i need to span the table over multiple pages).
How to change specific table line color and line width ?

for example, i am using this code, but the green line is exeeding the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{longtable}

\definecolor{greenTable}{RGB}{61,205,88}
\definecolor{grayTable}{RGB}{216,217,218}

\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{grayTable}
\begin{longtable}{l|l}
    
    \textbf{Parameter} &\textbf{Value}   \\
    \noalign{{ 
        \color{greenTable} 
        \hrule height 1.5pt
        }}
    abc&123\\
    \hline
    abc&123\\
    \hline
    abc&123\\
    \hline
    abc&123\\
    \hline
    abc&123\\
    \hline
    abc&123\\
    \hline
    abc&123\\
    \hline
    abc&123\\
    \noalign{{ \color{greenTable} \hrule height 1.5pt}}
   
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: use `\hline` and `\arrayrulecolor` from the colortbl package

Comment: Why do you use `\hrule` instead of `\hline`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I need to change its width also

Comment: @Mico not possible to change the color and width at the same time with \hline if i well understood

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232573/how-to-change-width-of-concrete-hline-in-table/232587#232587

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for your comment, but i really dont find the solution there. 

what i need is just to have table that can span over multiple pages, and have the second and last line with a green bold line as shown in the picture. 

PS: if using the normal tabular environtment, the \hrule will only stop at the table limit. but i need the table to span over multiple pages, so i use long table and this problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is missing the `colortbl` package, which is what provides `\arrayrulecolor`. Does the following do what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\definecolor{greenTable}{RGB}{61,205,88}
\definecolor{grayTable}{RGB}{216,217,218}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{l|l}
    \textbf{Parameter} &\textbf{Value}   \\
\arrayrulecolor{greenTable}
      \hline
\arrayrulecolor{grayTable}
    abc&123\\
    \hline
    abc&123\\
    \hline
    abc&123\\
    \hline
    abc&123\\
    \hline
    abc&123\\
    \hline
    abc&123\\
    \hline
    abc&123\\
    \hline
    abc&123\\
\arrayrulecolor{greenTable}
    \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe OP also wanna change the line width.

Comment: @Tom indeed, seems it's not possible with longtable environtment ?